# Minimizing overhead due to the large number of Numpy dot calls

Tags: performance, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

My problem is the following, I have an iterative algorithm such that at each iteration it needs to perform several matrix-matrix multiplications dot(**A_i**, **B_i**), for i = 1 ... k. Since these multiplications are being performed with Numpy's dot, I know they are calling BLAS-3 implementation, which is quite fast. The problem is that the number of calls is huge and it turned out to be a bottleneck in my program. I would like to minimize the overhead due all these calls by making less products but with bigger matrices.

For simplicity, consider that all matrices are n x n (usually n is not big, it ranges between 1 and 1000). One way around to my problem would be to consider the block diagonal matrix diag(**A_i**) and perform the product below.

[image: diag_blk]

This is just one call to the function dot but now the program wastes a lot of times performing multiplication with zeros. This idea doesn't seem to work but it gives the result [**A_1 B_1**, ..., **A_k B_k**], that is, all products stacked in a single big matrix.

My question is this, is there a way to compute [**A_1 B_1**, ..., **A_k B_k**] with a single function call?  Or even more to the point, how can I compute these products faster than making a loop of Numpy dots?

Comment: Others have noticed that `n` calls to `dot` can be faster than one call on with array `n` times larger.  Memory management overhead eats into the time savings from doing fewer iterations.  Another way to put it, a 'few' iterations on a complex task might actually be optimal.  It this case, unless there's BLAS level code that can handle block-dot, your original iteration might well be fastest.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for your comment. Do you mind to give some reference about what other have noticed? I'm interested.

Comment: n x n ranging from 1 to 1_000 is quite a large area. With quite small n (<20) arrays a custom Cython or Numba function is by far faster than the @ operator (calling a Blas routine. For larger n the BLAS routine will be the fastest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It depends on the size of the matrices

**Edit**

For larger nxn matrices (aprox. size 20) a BLAS call from compiled code is faster, for smaller matrices custom Numba or Cython Kernels are usually faster.

The following method generates custom dot- functions for given input shapes. With this method it is also possible to benefit from compiler related optimizations like loop unrolling, which are especially important for small matrices.

It has to be noted, that generating and compiling one kernel takes approx. 1s, therefore make sure to call the generator only if you really have to.

**Generator function**

```
def gen_dot_nm(x,y,z):
    #small kernels
    @nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
    def dot_numba(A,B):
        """
        calculate dot product for (x,y)x(y,z)
        """
        assert A.shape[0]==B.shape[0]
        assert A.shape[2]==B.shape[1]

        assert A.shape[1]==x
        assert B.shape[1]==y
        assert B.shape[2]==z

        res=np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[1],B.shape[2]),dtype=A.dtype)
        for ii in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
            for i in range(x):
                for j in range(z):
                    acc=0.
                    for k in range(y):
                        acc+=A[ii,i,k]*B[ii,k,j]
                    res[ii,i,j]=acc
        return res

    #large kernels
    @nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
    def dot_BLAS(A,B):
        assert A.shape[0]==B.shape[0]
        assert A.shape[2]==B.shape[1]

        res=np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[1],B.shape[2]),dtype=A.dtype)
        for ii in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
            res[ii]=np.dot(A[ii],B[ii])
        return res

    #At square matices above size 20
    #calling BLAS is faster
    if x>=20 or y>=20 or z>=20:
        return dot_BLAS
    else:
        return dot_numba
```

**Usage example**

```
A=np.random.rand(1000,2,2)
B=np.random.rand(1000,2,2)

dot22=gen_dot_nm(2,2,2)
X=dot22(A,B)
%timeit X3=dot22(A,B)
#5.94 µs ± 21.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Old answer**

Another alternative, but with more work to do, would be to use some special BLAS implementations, which creates [custom kernels](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-improved-small-matrix-performance-using-just-in-time-jit-code) for very small matrices just in time and than calling this kernels from C.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

#Don't use this for larger submatrices
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def dot(A,B):
    assert A.shape[0]==B.shape[0]
    assert A.shape[2]==B.shape[1]

    res=np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[1],B.shape[2]),dtype=A.dtype)
    for ii in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for i in range(A.shape[1]):
            for j in range(B.shape[2]):
                acc=0.
                for k in range(B.shape[1]):
                    acc+=A[ii,i,k]*B[ii,k,j]
                res[ii,i,j]=acc
    return res

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def dot_22(A,B):
    assert A.shape[0]==B.shape[0]
    assert A.shape[1]==2
    assert A.shape[2]==2
    assert B.shape[1]==2
    assert B.shape[2]==2

    res=np.empty((A.shape[0],A.shape[1],B.shape[2]),dtype=A.dtype)
    for ii in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        res[ii,0,0]=A[ii,0,0]*B[ii,0,0]+A[ii,0,1]*B[ii,1,0]
        res[ii,0,1]=A[ii,0,0]*B[ii,0,1]+A[ii,0,1]*B[ii,1,1]
        res[ii,1,0]=A[ii,1,0]*B[ii,0,0]+A[ii,1,1]*B[ii,1,0]
        res[ii,1,1]=A[ii,1,0]*B[ii,0,1]+A[ii,1,1]*B[ii,1,1]
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
A=np.random.rand(1000,2,2)
B=np.random.rand(1000,2,2)

X=A@B
X2=np.einsum("xik,xkj->xij",A,B)
X3=dot_22(A,B) #avoid measurig compilation overhead
X4=dot(A,B)    #avoid measurig compilation overhead

%timeit X=A@B
#262 µs ± 2.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit np.einsum("xik,xkj->xij",A,B,optimize=True)
#264 µs ± 3.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit X3=dot_22(A,B)
#5.68 µs ± 27.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit X4=dot(A,B)
#9.79 µs ± 61.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I have some experience with Numba so this answer is very welcomed. Just give me some time try this out. A little question: does the assert line gives some speed up? Why? Thank you!

Comment: @Integral It can give speedups because it also informs the compiler of the exact memory layout. But the main reason is to avoid crashes. There is no bounds checking, so if you run out of bounds Python will simply crash or the function produces nonsense (The same behavour than a C routine or Cython with turned off bound checking)

Comment: I understand that your dot_22 is faster because you eliminate a loop by writing each result explicitly. You think this approach still works for a generic dot_nn ? I mean works in the sense of being faster .

Comment: @Integral Yes that's possible. Do you have a wide range of different array shapes or just a few?

Answer (score 1):

You can stack the arrays to have shape (k, n, n), and call `numpy.matmul` or use the `@` operator.

For example,

```
In [18]: A0 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])                                                                 

In [19]: A1 = np.array([[1, 2], [-3, 5]])                                                                

In [20]: A2 = np.array([[4, 0], [1, 1]])                                                                 

In [21]: B0 = np.array([[1, 4], [-3, 4]])                                                                

In [22]: B1 = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 1]])                                                                 

In [23]: B2 = np.array([[-2, 9], [0, 1]])                                                                

In [24]: np.matmul([A0, A1, A2], [B0, B1, B2])                                                           
Out[24]: 
array([[[-5, 12],
        [-9, 28]],

       [[ 4,  3],
        [-1,  2]],

       [[-8, 36],
        [-2, 10]]])
```

Or, using `@`:

```
In [32]: A = np.array([A0, A1, A2])                                                                      

In [33]: A                                                                                               
Out[33]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [-3,  5]],

       [[ 4,  0],
        [ 1,  1]]])

In [34]: B = np.array([B0, B1, B2])                                                                      

In [35]: A @ B                                                                                           
Out[35]: 
array([[[-5, 12],
        [-9, 28]],

       [[ 4,  3],
        [-1,  2]],

       [[-8, 36],
        [-2, 10]]])
```

Comment: thanks, this seem to handle all products in a single call. Is this approach faster?

Comment: It doesn't work in numba so it literally ignores the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to waste time multiplying zeros, then what you really want are sparse matrices.  Using `A` and `B` matrices from @WarrenWeckesser:

```
from scipy import sparse
sparse.block_diag((A0, A1, A2), format = "csr") @ np.concatenate((B0, B1, B2), axis = 0)
Out[]: 
array([[-5, 12],
       [-9, 28],
       [ 4,  3],
       [-1,  2],
       [-8, 36],
       [-2, 10]], dtype=int32)
```

This is likely a speedup for large matrices.  For smaller ones @max9111 probably has the right idea using `numba`.