# Optimization of code snippet including multiple np.multipy statements

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, multiplication

I working on optimizing some code in a python module. I have pinned down the bottleneck and is a code snippet which does some computation in `numpy`. Namely the following code:

```
    xh = np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 0], x )
    xh += np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 1],  y) 
    xh += np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 2],  h)
    yh = np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 0],  x) 
    yh += np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 1],  y) 
    yh += np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 2],  h)
    q = np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 0],  x) 
    q += np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 1],  y) 
    q += np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 2],  h)
```

where x,y and h are np.ndarray with shape (4206,5749) and `K_Rinv` is a `np.ndarray` with shape `(3,3)`. 
This code snippet is called multiple times and takes more 50% of the time of the whole code. 
Is there a way to speed this up ? Or is it just as it is and can't be speed up.

**Edit1:**
Thanks for the answers. After having trouble with numba( see Error message at the end ) i tried the suggestion with numexpr. However my code broke when using this solution. So i checked if the results where the same and they are not. Here is the code i'm using:

```
    xh_1 = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[0, 0], 'b1': x,
                                                'a2': K_Rinv[0, 1], 'b2': y,
                                                'a3': K_Rinv[0, 2], 'b3': h})
    yh_1 = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[1, 0], 'b1': x,
                                                'a2': K_Rinv[1, 1], 'b2': y,
                                                'a3': K_Rinv[1, 2], 'b3': h})
    q_1 = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[2, 0], 'b1': x,
                                            'a2': K_Rinv[2, 1], 'b2': y,
                                            'a3': K_Rinv[2, 2], 'b3': h})
    xh_2 = np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 0], x )
    xh_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 1],  y) 
    xh_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 2],  h)
    yh_2 = np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 0],  x) 
    yh_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 1],  y) 
    yh_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 2],  h)
    q_2 = np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 0],  x) 
    q_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 1],  y) 
    q_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 2],  h)
    check1 = xh_1.all() == xh_2.all() 
    check2 = yh_1.all() == yh_2.all() 
    check3 = q_2.all() == q_1.all()
    print ( " Check1 :{} , Check2: {} , Check3:{}" .format (check1,check2,check3))
```

I don't have any experience with numexpr, is it usual that thery are not the same?

Error from numba:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 420, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 353, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 768, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 77, in compile
    status, retval = self._compile_cached(args, return_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 91, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 109, in _compile_core
    pipeline_class=self.pipeline_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 551, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 327, in compile_extra
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 321, in compile_extra
    ExtractByteCode().run_pass(self.state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/untyped_passes.py", line 67, in run_pass
    bc = bytecode.ByteCode(func_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/bytecode.py", line 215, in __init__
    self._compute_lineno(table, code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numba/bytecode.py", line 237, in _compute_lineno
    known = table[_FIXED_OFFSET].lineno
KeyError: 2
```

**Edit2**
Tanks for the comments and answers. 
So after going over the code againg the numexpr solution works.Thank you very much. I still did some testing in a seperate python file to see if the numba code works there and it does but very slow. See the code i'm using below:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import numexpr
from datetime import datetime

def calc(x,y,h,K_Rinv):
        xh_2 = np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 0], x )
        xh_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 1],  y) 
        xh_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[0, 2],  h)
        yh_2 = np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 0],  x) 
        yh_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 1],  y) 
        yh_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[1, 2],  h)
        q_2 = np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 0],  x) 
        q_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 1],  y) 
        q_2 += np.multiply(K_Rinv[2, 2],  h)
        return xh_2, yh_2, q_2

def calc_numexpr(x,y,h,K_Rinv):
    xh = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[0, 0], 'b1': x,
                                            'a2': K_Rinv[0, 1], 'b2': y,
                                            'a3': K_Rinv[0, 2], 'b3': h})
    yh = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[1, 0], 'b1': x,
                                            'a2': K_Rinv[1, 1], 'b2': y,
                                            'a3': K_Rinv[1, 2], 'b3': h})
    q = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[2, 0], 'b1': x,
                                           'a2': K_Rinv[2, 1], 'b2': y,
                                           'a3': K_Rinv[2, 2], 'b3': h})
    return xh,yh,q


@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def calc_nb(x,y,h,K_Rinv):
    xh=np.empty_like(x)
    yh=np.empty_like(x)
    q=np.empty_like(x)

    for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            xh[i,j]=K_Rinv[0, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[0, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[0, 2]*h[i,j]
            yh[i,j]=K_Rinv[1, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[1, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[1, 2]*h[i,j]
            q[i,j] =K_Rinv[2, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[2, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[2, 2]*h[i,j]
    return xh,yh,q


x = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
y = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
h = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
K_Rinv = np.random.random((3, 3))

start = datetime.now()
x_calc,y_calc,q_calc = calc(x,y,h,K_Rinv)
end = datetime.now()
print("Calc took:           {} ".format(end - start))

start = datetime.now()
x_numexpr,y_numexpr,q_numexpr = calc_numexpr(x,y,h,K_Rinv)
end = datetime.now()
print("Calc_numexpr took:   {} ".format(end - start))

start = datetime.now()
x_nb,y_nb,q_nb = calc_nb(x,y,h,K_Rinv)
end = datetime.now()
print("Calc nb took:        {} ".format(end - start))

check_nb_q = (q_calc==q_nb).all()
check_nb_y = (y_calc==y_nb).all()
check_nb_x = (x_calc==x_nb).all()

check_numexpr_q = (q_calc==q_numexpr).all()
check_numexpr_y = (y_calc==y_numexpr).all()
check_numexpr_x = (x_calc==x_numexpr).all()

print("Checks for numexpr: {} , {} ,{} \nChecks for nb: {} ,{}, {}" .format(check_numexpr_x,check_numexpr_y,check_numexpr_q,check_nb_x,check_nb_y,check_nb_q))
```

which outpus the following:

```
Calc took:           0:00:01.944150 
Calc_numexpr took:   0:00:00.616224 
Calc nb took:        0:00:01.553058 
Checks for numexpr: True , True ,True 
Checks for nb: False ,False, False
```

so the numba version doens't work as expected. Any Idea what i'm doing wrong? Would love to get the numba solution working as well.

Ps. nb.**version** is '0.47.0'

Comment: @LucaNeri, `numpy` is a bit of a special tag in that vectorizing calculations is the whole point of the package - so we don't kick much to CodeReview.

Comment: Which Numba version are you using `nb.__version__`? Have you tried to exactly replicate my example?

Comment: That's a timings issue. Numba is a jit compiler and the compilation takes aprox. 1s, but only on the first call. All further calls are a lot faster.

Comment: @max9111 Thanks again. Think it is time for me to google what a jit compiler is :) . Ps. the second call is indeed faster namely. 0.8s , still not as fast as numexpr. By the way the fact that the result is not the same, any idea?

Comment: The fastmath flag https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-floating-point-behavior changes the results slightly. In detail I expect a bit different results because of SIMD-vectorization (FMA3 instruction) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add You will get True if you check with np.allclose(), but you can also disable fastmath. Regarding timing: 1) check with fastmath=False, 2) Have you put a additional line `x_nb,y_nb,q_nb = calc_nb(x,y,h,K_Rinv)` before you start the timing?

Comment: @max9111 Thank you. You are right. With fastmath flag set to False the result are the same. Strange thing is with the fastmath flag the computation is slower. With fastmath=True it is 0.79s while without it is 0.75s ( not average only one run) .. while numexpr took only 0.66s

Comment: Interesting. Only for curiosity: Which processor/RAM are you using? Since all of your timings are quite slow I expect something low-end? Does turning of parallelization is also beneficial?

Comment: @max9111 processor: i7-8850H CPU@ 2.6 GHZ ; RAM 16GB ...  However as i don't have the target system at hand right now i'm using wsl ubuntu 18.04.. Don't know if that has any influence. Probably it does ?

Comment: @max9111 With the parallel flag set to False  it is faster! Namely the same speed as numexpr. Seems that wsl has no support for parallelism. Probably i should just wait until i have acess to the target system and try on there. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The only issue I can imagine would be that you only have a one RAM module installed, which is quite common in Notebooks nowadays. This would reduce the memory bandwidth by 50% (which is the limmiting part here) In this case it would be recommendable to invest a few bucks in a second module.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `numexpr` too speed up the calculations:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr

x = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
y = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
h = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
K_Rinv = np.random.random((3, 3))

xh = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[0, 0], 'b1': x,
                                            'a2': K_Rinv[0, 1], 'b2': y,
                                            'a3': K_Rinv[0, 2], 'b3': h})
yh = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[1, 0], 'b1': x,
                                            'a2': K_Rinv[1, 1], 'b2': y,
                                            'a3': K_Rinv[1, 2], 'b3': h})
q = numexpr.evaluate('a1*b1+a2*b2+a3*b3', {'a1': K_Rinv[2, 0], 'b1': x,
                                           'a2': K_Rinv[2, 1], 'b2': y,
                                           'a3': K_Rinv[2, 2], 'b3': h})
```

On my machine this is around 5x faster than without `numexpr`.

Another thing is that I would prefer to use matrix multiplication and broadcasting with `numpy` if you are dealing with matrices instead of splitting up the multiplications and additions:

```
xyh_mat = np.concatenate([x[:, :, np.newaxis],
                          y[:, :, np.newaxis],
                          h[:, :, np.newaxis]], axis=-1)[:, :, :, np.newaxis]  
# (4206, 5749, 3, 1)
K_Rinv_mat = K_Rinv[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, :]  
# (1, 1, 3, 3)


xyh_mat_2 = np.einsum("ijkl, ijlk->ijk", K_Rinv_mat, xyh_mat)
# 1.25x faster

xyh_mat_2 = K_Rinv_mat @ xyh_mat
# 3x slower

# xh = xyh_mat_2[:, :, 0]
# yh = xyh_mat_2[:, :, 1]
# q = xyh_mat_2[:, :, 2]
```

However it seems that there is no speed advantage gained from using `numpy` in this case, which is a little bit surprising to me.

## EDIT

regarding the comment on further computations:

```
np.divide(xh, q, x)
np.divide(yh, q, y)
# should translate to:
x = numexpr.evaluate('a/b', {'a': xh , 'b': q })
y = numexpr.evaluate('a/b', {'a': yh , 'b': q })
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the same thing.  No speedup from BLAS?  Weird.

Comment: @scleronomic I have another computation: np.divide(xh,q,x) and  np.divide(yh,q,y). i thought i could just use numexpr again to also speed things up and replace the np.divide statement with x = numexpr.evaluate('a/b', {'a' : xh , 'b' , h }) .. However this breaks my code. Aren't this statements the same? Or at least isn't x the same after those two statements?

Comment: I updated my answer, I guess you just mixed up some variables, you are not using `h` in your first calculation

Comment: @scleronomic Thanks for your answer. Oops my fault.Just for info: Apparently there is no speed up when using numexpr compared to np.divide

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be to use Numba.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def calc_nb(x,y,h,K_Rinv):
    xh=np.empty_like(x)
    yh=np.empty_like(x)
    q=np.empty_like(x)

    for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            xh[i,j]=K_Rinv[0, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[0, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[0, 2]*h[i,j]
            yh[i,j]=K_Rinv[1, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[1, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[1, 2]*h[i,j]
            q[i,j] =K_Rinv[2, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[2, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[2, 2]*h[i,j]
    return xh,yh,q
```

**Is this calculation memory-bandwidth limited?**

```
def copy(x,y,h,K_Rinv):
    return np.copy(x),np.copy(y),np.copy(h)

%timeit copy(x,y,h,K_Rinv)
#147 ms ± 4.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This calculation is limited by memory-bandwidth and by dynamic memory-allocation, the multiplications in between are irrelevant for performance.

**Timings**

```
x = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
y = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
h = np.random.random((4206, 5749))
K_Rinv = np.random.random((3, 3))

%timeit calc(x,y,h,K_Rinv) #Your implementation
#581 ms ± 8.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit calc_nb(x,y,h,K_Rinv)
#145 ms ± 3.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit calc_numexpr_scleronomic(x,y,h,K_Rinv)
#175 ms ± 1.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit calc_Daniel_F(x,y,h,K_Rinv)
#589 ms ± 24.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Possible further optimizations: Reuse of already allocated memory**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def calc_nb_2(x,y,h,K_Rinv,xh,yh,q):
    for i in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            xh[i,j]=K_Rinv[0, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[0, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[0, 2]*h[i,j]
            yh[i,j]=K_Rinv[1, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[1, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[1, 2]*h[i,j]
            q[i,j] =K_Rinv[2, 0]*x[i,j]+K_Rinv[2, 1]*  y[i,j]+K_Rinv[2, 2]*h[i,j]
    return xh,yh,q

#allocate memory only once if you call this function repeatedly
xh=np.empty_like(x)
yh=np.empty_like(x)
q=np.empty_like(x)

%timeit calc_nb_2(x,y,h,K_Rinv,xh,yh,q)
69.2 ms ± 194 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I always expect `numba` to win a speed race, but I didn't expect it (and `numexpr` which I think is based on `numba`) to beat `@` and `einsum` (both of which have BLAS backends) so handily on a linear algebra problem.

Comment: @DanielF BLAS calls are very slow on a bunch of small matrices. exampe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774 Both numexpr and numba do jit compilation, but they are not based one one another. While numba is related to Clang or Flang. (Clang C-> LLVM-IR, Numba Python ->LLVM-IR)

Comment: Huh. I though the original purpose of BLAS was 3D graphics, which is all 3x3 linear algebra

Comment: I thought it would be enough that only one matrix of the calculation is *big*, for BLAS to be effective

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that's just and expanded dot product:

```
x_y_h = np.stack([x, y, h], axis = 0)
xh_yh_q = np.einsum('ij, jkl -> ikl', K_Rinv, x_y_h)
[xh, yh, q] = list(xh_yh_q)
```