# Optimize this existing 3D Numpy Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have code some that has just been completed. It works as intended. I have opted to use `dot` in Numpy as, to my limited experience, it is faster than usual forms of matrix multiplication if you have BLAS installed on your system. However, you will note than I have had to transpose a lot of stuff. I'm note sure of this then actually outweighs the benefit of using `dot`.

I provide the mathematical equation as was found in the paper. Note that is a recursion

[image]

Here is my code implementation:

I provide the necessary components and their dimensions first

```
P = array([[0.73105858, 0.26894142],
           [0.26894142, 0.73105858]])  # shape (K,K)

B = array([[6.07061629e-09, 0.00000000e+00],
           [0.00000000e+00, 2.57640371e-10]])  # shape (K,K)

dP = array([[[ 0.19661193, -0.19661193],
             [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

           [[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
            [ 0.19661193, -0.19661193]],

           [[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        ]],

           [[ 0.        ,  0.        ],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        ]]])  # shape (L,K,K)

dB = array([[[ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
             [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]],

            [[ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
             [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]],

            [[-1.16721049e-09,  0.00000000e+00],
             [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]],

            [[ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
             [ 0.00000000e+00, -1.27824683e-09]]])  # shape (L,K,K)

a = array([[[ 7.60485178e-08,  5.73923956e-07]],

           [[-5.54100398e-09, -8.75213012e-08]],

           [[-1.25878643e-08, -1.48361081e-07]],

           [[-2.73494035e-08, -1.74585971e-07]]])  # shape (L,1,K)

alpha = array([[0.11594542, 0.88405458]])  # shape (1,K)

c = 1  # scalar
```

Here is the actual Numpy calculation. Note all the transpose use.

```
term1 = (a/c).dot(P).dot(B)
term2 = dP.transpose((0,2,1)).dot(alpha.T).transpose((0,2,1)).dot(B)
term3 = dB.dot(  P.T.dot(alpha.T) ).transpose((0,2,1))
a = term1 + term2 + term3
```

One then should get:

```
>>> a
array([[[ 1.38388584e-10, -5.87312190e-12]],

       [[ 1.05516813e-09, -4.47819530e-11]],

       [[-3.76451117e-10, -2.88160549e-17]],

       [[-4.06412069e-16, -8.65984406e-10]]])
```

Note that the shape of `alpha` as well as `a` has been chosen by me. These can be changed if you find it to provide superior performance.

I would like to point out that I think that the existing code is fast. Actually, very fast. However, I keep wondering if one could do better. Please do give it a go. I have profiled my code (which has a lot of Numpy broadcasting and vectorization) and this is not necessarily a bottleneck as it takes 23 micro seconds to evaluate on my very old machine. However, it is a single step of a recursion. This means that it is evaluated `N` times in a sequential manner. Hence, even the tiniest of gains would make a large difference for a large sequence.

Thank you for your time.

## EDIT/UPDATE:

Thanks to @max9111, who suggested that I look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347796/minimizing-overhead-due-to-the-large-number-of-numpy-dot-calls/59356461#59356461), I have managed some Numba code that runs faster than the Numpy calculation for `a`. It takes 14 microseconds as opposed to the original 23.

Here it is:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,boundscheck=False)
def get_next_a(a,alpha,P,dP,B,dB,c):
    N,M,_ = dP.shape
    new_a = np.zeros((N,1,M),dtype=np.float64)
    new_a = np.zeros((N,1,M))
    entry = 0
    for idx in nb.prange(N):
        for i in range(M):
            for j in range(M):
                term1 =  a[idx,0,j]*P[j,i]*B[i,i]/c
                term2 = alpha[0,j]*dP[idx,j,i]*B[i,i] 
                term3 = alpha[0,j]*P[j,i]*dB[idx,i,i]
                entry += term1 + term2 + term3
            new_a[idx,0,i] = entry
            entry = 0
    return new_a
```

One will see that `get_next_a` returns the desired result. However, when I call it in a pure python function that contains Numpy the it complains. Here is a snippet of my actual code:

```
def forward_recursions(X,working_params):

#    P,dP,B,dB,pi,dpi = setup(X,working_params) 
    # Dummy Data and Parameters instead of setup
    working_params = np.random.uniform(0,2,size=100)
    X = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1000)
    P = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(10,10))
    norm = P.sum(axis=1)
    P = P/norm[:,None]
    dP = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(100,10,10))
    # We pretend that all 1000 of the 10 x 10 matrices 
    # only have diagonal entries
    B = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(1000,10,10)) 
    dB = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(1000,100,10,10))
    pi = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=10)
    norm = pi.sum()
    pi = (pi/norm).reshape(1,10)
    dpi = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(100,1,10))

    T = len(X)
    N = len(working_params)
    M = np.int(np.sqrt(N))
    ones = np.ones((M,1))


    alpha = pi.dot(B[0])
    scale = alpha.dot(ones)
    alpha = alpha/scale
    ll = np.log(scale)
    a = dpi.dot(B[0]) + dB[0].dot(pi.T).transpose((0,2,1))
    for t in range(1,T):

        old_scale = scale
        alpha = alpha.dot(P).dot(B[t])
        scale = alpha.dot(ones)
        ll += np.log(scale)
        alpha = alpha/scale

        # HERE IS THE NUMBA FUNCTION

        a = get_next_a(a,alpha,P,dP,B[t],dB[t],old_scale)

    dll = a.dot(ones).reshape((N,1))/scale
    return ll,dll,a
```

I know that the inclusion of my own code depends on other functions that are not included and hence means that `forward_recursions` will not run. I just hope for it to perhaps give some perspective.

The error I get is

```
TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function iadd>) with argument(s) of type(s): (Literal[int](0), array(float64, 2d, C))
Known signatures:
 * (int64, int64) -> int64
 * (int64, uint64) -> int64
 * (uint64, int64) -> int64
 * (uint64, uint64) -> uint64
 * (float32, float32) -> float32
 * (float64, float64) -> float64
 * (complex64, complex64) -> complex64
 * (complex128, complex128) -> complex128
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 8:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 9:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 10:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 11:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 12:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 13:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 14:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 15:
    All templates rejected without literals.
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at <ipython-input-251-50e636317ef8> (13)
```

I do not understand what this means. Do you perhaps know how I can fix something like this. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: How large is the target-use **`N ~ 1E6`**? **`~ 1E9`**? **`~ 1E12`**?

Comment: I would say between ```N ~ 1E3 ``` and ```N ~ 1E6```.

Comment: Thanks, similarly how large are the target-use sizings of **`L ~ 1E{?|3|6|9|…}`**? and **`K ~ 1E{?|3|6|9|…}`**?

Comment: The dimensions are those of a Hidden Markov Model such that they are not too large. ```K ~ 10``` whereas ```L ~ K**2 ~ 100```.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read (faster or not) if you write simple einsums. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html Since you are calculation a lot of tiny matrix or matrix-vector products (there is no BLAS algorithm for more than 2D) this can be very likely improved as shown in this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774

Comment: @max9111 Thank you so much for this recommendation. This is very interesting news about the BLAS algorithm. I will definitely be giving your answer to the other question a go. As for the ```einsum```, it seems very new to me. However, I am going to try and learn it as best that I can.

Comment: @max9111 I have a working version that replaces my computation of ```a``` using Numba. It is based on the example that you have given. It is faster than the Numpy version. However, when I call the function inside another Python function then it complains ```TypingError: Invalid use of Function```. I know this is very vague. Can I post another question based on this issue, should I post my solution here as an answer so you might have a look if you wish or do you perhaps have an idea already of what it might be? You seem to know a lot about Numba. May I please ask for your help.

Comment: Just das it to your question.

Comment: @max9111 Thank you very much. I will add it as an edit. On the toy example given, it performs 14 micro seconds when compiled as opposed to 23 micro seconds when originally using Numpy. I will post another comment when the question has been edited. Thank you very much.

Comment: @max9111 I have updated the question as promised. I hope that I have provided enough background.

Comment: But it is running without jit-compilation right? I need some dummydata for all missing inputs eg. `P,dP,B,dB,pi,dpi,N`. Can be produced by np.random.rand(), but all of them should have the same shape as in reality. It looks like a problem with the array shapes. Performance: Parallelizing this tiny function is also likely not beneficial (actually high negative impact on runtime). You can also add some other things like error_model="numpy" to disable division by zero check to mention some things.

Comment: @max9111 It does indeed run perfectly without the jit-compilation. I have added some dummy data to my question of appropriate dimensions. Thank you for the error_model suggestion.

Comment: @max9111 I have figured out what the problem is. Numba does not recognise non-Numba functions if they are nested in the Numba function being compiled. I have written up an answer to my own question where I provide a resolved working Numba script thanks to your help. ```error_model='numpy'``` seems to slow things down on my computer. I also share in my answer two opinions/philosophies that I think one can apply when working with Numba such that it does not clash with Numy and Python functions. I really hope to see Numba grow to incorporate more Numpy in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to post an answer to my own question. I would like to thank @max9111 and @user3666197 for their kind help and advice. I have used what they have taught me in order to produce optimized code using Numba.

I had some struggles with Numba though. One will note that my optimized Numba version had trouble running in a Python function (as was pointed out in my edit/update section). I now understand why.

Numba is really awesome as it is really fast. Plus one has calculations that is very explicit as compared perhaps to Numpy. Numpy produces shorter code and for me is more mathematically concise to actually read. Furthermore, Numpy seamlessly works with native Python and as a result is very trouble free to code with. Personally, I think Numpy is the fastest way to produce working script that is guaranteed to run fast. Numba does not play that well as Numpy. In fact, it and Numpy don't get along very well. As an example, Numpy's beloved `dot` cannot be used in Numba.

Numba requires one to change one's coding style a bit. I would like to think one uses the functional paradigm of coding with Numba: a function has input and it output where the output may flow into another function via its input. In other word, if you want to deposit data into another function, you can't nest the data-producing function into the one that is going to process it. You have to produce the data and then feed it into the processing function via its arguments.

Nesting does work, however, but do realize that the function you are nesting must also be a Numba compiled function. My code did not work because `setup` was a nested Python function. Numba could not recognise it hence `TypingError: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function iadd>)`. So, if you want to nest functions then you have to make sure all your functions are Numba functions. This is actually quite constraining and would take away from the beauty of scripting things fast in Python. As a result, that is why I mentioned not nesting functions in Numba because this gives you the freedom of not having to make all your functions Numba.

Why would one not want all your functions to be in Numba if it is so fast then? Simple, Numpy broadcasting and vectorization is scary fast Faster than Numba for certain applications such as computing a probability density function for many data points and parameters. Plus, you still want to use things like numpy.linalg.solve etc.

Here is my optimized version:

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,boundscheck=False)
def forward_recursions_numba(X,
                             P,
                             dP,
                             B,
                             dB,
                             pi,
                             dpi):

#    P,dP,B,dB,pi,dpi = setup(X,working_params) # does not work with numba
#    print(P)

    T = len(X)
    N,M,_ = dP.shape
#    ones = np.ones((M,1))


#    alpha = pi.dot(B[0])
#    scale = alpha.dot(ones)
    alpha = np.zeros((1,M))
    scale = 0
    for i in range(M):
        alpha[0,i] = pi[0,i]*B[0,i,i]
        scale += alpha[0,i]

    alpha = alpha/scale
    ll = np.log(scale)


#    a = dpi.dot(B[0]) + dB[0].dot(pi.T).transpose((0,2,1))
    a = np.zeros((N,1,M))
    for idx in range(N):
        for i in range(M):
            a[idx,0,i] = dpi[idx,0,i]*B[0,i,i] + pi[0,i]*dB[0,idx,i,i]

    for t in range(1,T):
        old_scale = scale
#        alpha = alpha.dot(P).dot(B[t])
#        scale = alpha.dot(ones)
        scale = 0
        alpha_new = np.zeros(alpha.shape)
        for i  in range(M):
            entry = 0
            for j in range(M):
                entry += alpha[0,j]*P[j,i]*B[t,i,i]
            alpha_new[0,i] = entry
            scale += alpha_new[0,i]

        ll += np.log(scale)
        alpha = alpha_new/scale

#        term1 = (a/old_scale).dot(P).dot(B[t])
#        term2 = dP.transpose((0,2,1)).dot(alpha.T).transpose((0,2,1)).dot(B[t])
#        term3 = dB[t].dot(  P.T.dot(alpha.T) ).transpose((0,2,1))
#        a = term1 + term2 + term3
        new_a = np.zeros((N,1,M))
        for idx in nb.prange(N):
            for i in range(M):
                entry = 0
                for j in range(M):
                    term1 =  a[idx,0,j]*P[j,i]*B[t,i,i]/old_scale
                    term2 = alpha[0,j]*dP[idx,j,i]*B[t,i,i] 
                    term3 = alpha[0,j]*P[j,i]*dB[t,idx,i,i]
                    entry += term1 + term2 + term3
                new_a[idx,0,i] = entry
        a = new_a

#    dll = a.dot(ones).reshape((N,1))/scale
    dll = np.zeros((N,1))
    for idx in nb.prange(N):
        dparam = 0
        for i in range(M):
            dparam += a[idx,0,i]
        dll[idx] = dparam/scale

    return ll,dll,a
```

If we runs it on some dummy data

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1000)
P = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(10,10))
norm = P.sum(axis=1)
P = P/norm[:,None]
dP = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(100,10,10))
# We pretend that all 1000 of the 10 x 10 matrices 
# only have diagonal entries
B = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(1000,10,10)) 
dB = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(1000,100,10,10))
pi = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=10)
norm = pi.sum()
pi = (pi/norm).reshape(1,10)
dpi = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(100,1,10))
```

Let us time it:

```
>>> %timeit forward_recursions_numba(X,P,dP,B,dB,pi,dpi)
51.3 ms ± 389 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Let us compare it to the Numpy dot version.

```
>>> %timeit forward_recursions(X,P,dP,B,dB,pi,dpi)
271 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**NOTE:** to get the Numpy version you can just re-comment the Numpy code, comment the Numba loops and comment the `@nb.njit` decorator out.

Using `lscpu` on my Lubuntu machine we can see that my specs are `Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6700  @ 2.66GHz` with `6 GB DDR2 RAM (800 MHz)`

So my code has been dramatically optimized. Plus, I have learned a lot. Thank you very much everyone for your kind help and patience.

Comment: As already said in the comments, this function should be quite a lot faster if you turn off parallelization (starting up threads and thread synchronization also takes some time). For other things that are not already supported you can wrap C-or Fortran code directly (if speed matters) or use object mode if it is only a small part and speed isn't the main concern.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *…if one could do better?*

Your as-is code executes on my  <sub>( seems even older )</sub>  machine not in the posted `~ 23 [us]`, but `~ 45 [ms]` for the first call and, enjoying all the pre-fetches into `iCACHE` and `dCACHE` hierarchies somewhere between **`~77..1xx [us]`**:

```
>>> from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
44679
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
149
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
113
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
128
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
82
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
100
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
77
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
97
>>> a
array([[[ 1.38387304e-10, -5.87323502e-12]],
       [[ 1.05516829e-09, -4.47819355e-11]],
       [[-3.76450816e-10, -2.60843400e-20]],
       [[-1.41384088e-18, -8.65984377e-10]]])
```

Interestingly, re-running the code many times, re-assigning the processing results back into **`a`** actually **does not change** the values in **`a`**:

```
>>> aClk.start(); a = ( a / c ).dot( P ).dot( B ) + dP.transpose( ( 0, 2, 1) ).dot( alpha.T ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ).dot( B ) + dB.dot(  P.T.dot( alpha.T ) ).transpose( ( 0, 2, 1 ) ); aClk.stop()
97
>>> a
array([[[ 1.38387304e-10, -5.87323502e-12]],    
       [[ 1.05516829e-09, -4.47819355e-11]],
       [[-3.76450816e-10, -2.60843400e-20]],
       [[-1.41384088e-18, -8.65984377e-10]]])
```

This means, the code, as-is, does a lot of work so as to finally deliver an invariant value of **`a`** *( a re-produced identity, at a cost of spending ~ XY [us] doing that - you being the only one to decide, if that is ok with your target-application or not )*

---

### Remarks about a wished-to-have space for an improvement :

Well, given the **`N`** `~ 1E(3..6)` and `K ~ 10` and `L ~ 100`, there is not much to expect from any improvement efforts, sponsored to re-solve the ( so far an **`a`**'s identity result ) wish to have improved performance.

The sought for improved target processing will repeat sequentially more than `~1,000x` … less than `~ 1,000,000x`, that means :

- RAM-bound issues are not cardinal, as cache effect on the static parts, all having sizes of but a few `[MB]`, will get reused from cache at shortest latencies possible
- CPU-bound issues are already pre-solved inside the design & engineering of the `numpy`-tools ( harnessing SIMD-resources of CPU and vector-aligned striding tricks, where feasible - so not much to expect from user-level coding )

Last, but not least, one may comment of the "***costs***"-of-transposing - **`numpy`** does nothing else for having to transpose a matrix, but a change in the order of indexing - nothing else. If this might have some effect, it could be expected rather from reviewing the **`FORTRAN`**-type of ordering or **`C`**-language type of ordering of the underlying storage of data-cells into the physical RAM, yet at scales of but **`1E1 x 1E1`** ~ **`1E2 x 1E1 x 1E1`** at max, this puts this aspect become negligible and well masked by the ***in-cache*** nature of the processing with zero-writebacks or other performance related impacts.

---

### RESULT :

Given all the facts & further observations above, the cheapest and the most reasonable step for indeed getting higher throughput of here defined computations, is to move onto a linearly-working degree-of-freedom here - the higher `[GHz]` CPU-chip, the better ( linear growth of performance here ) also having as large amount of the AVX-512 registers as possible and as large as possible L1i + L1d caches ( strategies of affinity-mapped avoidance of any other O/S noise are obvious for HPC-grade performance targets ) and there rely on the already smart **`numpy`** tools, fine-tuned for this mix of the CPU-resources for matrix processing ( if in a need to go beyond `float64` [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) representation, another story starts ).

Do not expect a User-level code to do way better than this, **`numpy`**-native SIMD-aligned processing can and will deliver.

Assembly inline could, for the above given scales, get an edge, yet at an immense human-labour costs of having to craft and test such an ultimate, yet rather an arcane change in the concept of the solution. Kindly let me know, if the Market indeed demands doing such a step.

Comment: This is so much more thorough than I could have ever wished for. Thank you very much for your detailed analysis and explanations. I am going to have to study your answer with care though as to fully understand all the knowledge that it encapsulates.

Comment: As for the invariant ```a```, this is due to the problem being that of a toy example. What I have actually been doing is to extend the forward algorithm for Hidden Markov Models. The algorithm goes through a data set of length ```N``` and updates ```alpha```(joint probability) at each iteration. Furthermore, ```B``` and ```dB``` are unique for each ```x```(datum). What my computation does is to compute the gradient of the log-likelihood during the forward recursion. At the end one has both the log-likelihood and it's exact derivative. So fortunately the in-variance is not an issue.

Comment: Your explanation regarding the transpose in Numpy has provided much clarity. I must conclude that Numpy is truly very impressive in what it does. This is even more so if one can use ```dot``` with BLAS installed. I think I should leave the code as is and move on to the next part of the project. Thank you so much for your help!