# How to conveniently use operations on numpy fortran contiguos arrays?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

Some numpy functions like `np.matmul(a, b)` have convenient behavior for stacks of matrices.

The manual states:

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

Thus, for `a.shape = (10 , 2, 4)` and `b.shape(10, 4, 2)` the statement`a @ b` is meaningful and will have shape `(10, 2, 2)`

However, I'm coming from the linear algebra world, where I'm used to a Fortran contiguous array layout.

The same `a` represented as a Fortran contiguous array would have shape `(4, 2, 10)` and similarly `b.shape = (2, 4, 10)`.

To do `a @ b` as before I would have to invoke
`(a.T @ b.T).T` .

Even worse, assume you naively created the same Fortran-contiguous array `a` with the behavior of `matmul` in mind, such that it has shape `(10, 4, 2)`.
Then `a.strides = (8, 80, 320)`  with the smallest stride in the 'stack' index, which actually should have highest stride.

Is this really the way to go or am I missing something?

Comment: With `matmul` the first dimension (of 3) is a 'batch' dimension (I don't think `order` changes that). So if you want to play with transpose, use `.transpose(0,2,1)`.  Make some small arrays, and see which arrangement makes most sense.

Comment: The transpose of a 2d 'C' order array is a 'F' order `view` of the same data.  It just changes the `shape` and `strides`.

Comment: The question is, why is that the default? Why would you want a stack of matrices, where the stride corresponding to the 'batch dimension' is the smallest?

Comment: but of course, I could use something like your `.transpose(0,2,1)` solution, but that looks very error-prone, doesn't it?

Comment: The Python specs for `matmul` define it in terms of dimensions.  `order` and `strides` are not mentioned. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/

Comment: And numpy arrays do always follow these guidelines? Also, is there a plain python equivalent for fortran contiguous arrays? If not, then I don't see why matmul could not behave differently for those kind of arrays.

Comment: Are your matrices really that small (2,4)x(4,2)? In this case you can do the work much faster if you implement a solution like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774 As said before A.T only changes the stride and metadata, which is very cheap.

Comment: @max9111 no, that depends, can have arbitrary sizes. But thanks for the reference to numba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `numpy` can handle all sorts of layouts, many details are designed with the "C" layout in mind. Good examples are how nested lists translate into arrays, and the way numpy operations batch excess dimensions as in the matmul case.

It is correct that results in `numpy` as a rule of thumb do not depend on array layout (FORTRAN,C,non-contiguous); speed, however, certainly does and heavily so:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = rng.random((100,111,200))
b = rng.random((111,77,200))
af = np.array(a,order="F")
bf = np.array(b,order="F")

np.allclose((b.T@a.T).T,(bf.T@af.T).T)
# True
timeit(lambda:(b.T@a.T).T,number=10)
# 5.972857117187232
timeit(lambda:(bf.T@af.T).T,number=10)
# 0.1994628761895001
```

In fact, sometimes it is totally worth it to non-lazily transpose, i.e. copy your data into the best layout:

```
timeit(lambda:(np.array(b.T,order="C")@np.array(a.T,order="C")).T,number=10)
# 0.3931349152699113
```

My advice: If you want speed and convenience it is probably best to go with the "C" layout, it doesn't take all that long to get used to and saves you a lot of potential headaches.

Comment: Is that discussed somewhere? Favoring 'consistency' of results over speed? Looks like quite a dubious decision to me. Especially, since I've seen no warning about such things in the explanation of F-contiguous arrays.

Comment: @dba I can't find fault with guaranteeing consistency. But I agree with you that something like the occasional performance warning would be nice. Also, pls note that stacked matmul is a particularly unfavorable example. I think but am not sure that as long as the matrices you are multiplying have at least one contiguous axis each, the thing is handled by blas and speed differences are minor. It is when matrices are fully strided (e.g. because the contiguous axis is used for stacking) that things really slow down which makes me suspect there is no blas routine for that.

Comment: What I wanted to say is, that one could also have 'consistent' behavior, if the matmul operator was order dependent. For now, I guess I'll just stay with FORTRAN arrays and use `np.einsum` for these kind of operations.

Answer (score 0):

numpy's matrix multiplication works regardless of the internal layout of the array. For example, here are two C-ordered arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(10, 2, 4)
>>> b = np.random.rand(10, 4, 2)
>>> print('a', a.shape, a.strides)
>>> print('b', b.shape, b.strides)
a (10, 2, 4) (64, 32, 8)
b (10, 4, 2) (64, 16, 8)
```

Here are the equivalent arrays in Fortran order:

```
>>> af = np.asfortranarray(a)
>>> bf = np.asfortranarray(b)
>>> print('af', af.shape, af.strides)
>>> print('bf', bf.shape, bf.strides)
af (10, 2, 4) (8, 80, 160)
bf (10, 4, 2) (8, 80, 320)
```

Numpy treats equivalent arrays as equivalent, regardless of their internal layout:

```
>>> np.allclose(a, af) and np.allclose(b, bf)
True
```

The results of a matrix multiplication do not depend on the internal layout:

```
>>> np.allclose(a @ b, af @ bf)
True
```

and you can even mix layouts if you wish:

```
>>> np.allclose(a @ bf, af @ b)
True
```

In short, the most convenient way to use Fortran-ordered arrays in numpy is to not worry about internal array layout: the shape is all that matters.

If your array shapes differ from what is expected by the [numpy matmul API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), your best bet is to reshape the arrays, for example using `a.transpose(2, 0, 1) @ b.transpose(2, 0, 1)` or similar, depending on what is appropriate for your use-case, but don't worry: for C or Fortran contiguous arrays, this operation only adjusts the metadata around the array view, it does not cause the underlying data buffer to be copied or re-ordered.

Comment: Maybe I should have made it clearer in my question, but I'm really worried about speed. While the C layout intuitively gives you a good layout in terms of matrix multiplication speed, the F layout does not.