# Why is this variable unused in this Numba function?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, jit, numba

I'm trying to speed up my code using Numba. My code uses a lot of numpy array matrix multiplication, so I thought I'd create a `jit`'ed version. I know that `jit` prefers its variables to be pre-allocated, so my function was this:

```
@njit(parallel = True)
def jdot(a,b):
    c = np.zeros((a.shape[0],b.shape[1]))
    c = a.dot(b)
    return c
```

But my IDE is telling me that the first instance of `c` is unused. What am I getting wrong here?

EDIT:
To add a little info: If I remove the redundant line in the version above and run a speed test, I get the the `jit`'ed version does *worse* than the ordinary. This tells me I'm definitely not using Numba correctly, and my suspicion is that pre-allocating `c` properly might be the solution - but like I say, I'm not sure how. Here's the speed testing code:

```
@jit(nopython = True, parallel = True)
def jdot(a,b):
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    return c

jdot(np.ones((4,5,)),np.ones((5,6))) #Compile ahead of test

t1 = timer()
testrange = 10^6
for i in range(testrange):
    a = np.random.randn(4, 5)
    b = np.random.randn(5, 6)
    jdot(a,b)
t2 = timer()
for i in range(testrange):
    a = np.random.randn(4, 5)
    b = np.random.randn(5, 6)
    a.dot(b)
t3 = timer()
Tratio = (t2-t1)/(t3-t2)
print(f"Timing Ratio is {Tratio}")
```

Which yields `Timing Ratio is 1.9013561547738118`

What to do?

Comment: You are re-defining c in the line below, without using the first definition of it, hence it is unused

Comment: How would I change the function such that I'm filling in the values of `c` without overwriting it? Is there a way to do this without essentially re-writing the `.dot` method?

Comment: Pre-allocating `c` isn't going to be the solution. Numba just can't do much to optimize this operation.

Comment: (Also `^` is XOR, so `10^6` is `12`. You want `**` there.)

Comment: You can change the line `c = a.dot(b)` to `np.dot(a,b,c)`. This will use the preallocated array. But it shouldn't make any difference since you allocate the output array anyway each time you call the function. What you can do is to also pass the resulting array to your jdot function. Anyway Numba makes a BLAS call, Numpy makes a BLAS call -> not much difference. If you have a lot of very small dot products it can make sense to reimplement dot in Numba (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774)

Comment: Generally in Python, 'preallocate' does not make much sense.  In `c=RHS`, the RHS creates an object which is then assigned to (or referenced by) the variable `c`.  A following `c=RHS1` just assigns a new object to `c`, throwing away the original `RHS` object.  The original assignment does not thing to improve the second - either time or memory wise.