# Fast subsequent multiplication of many matrices in python

Tags: python, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have to generate a matrix (propagator in physics) by ordered multiplication of many other matrices. Each matrix is about the size of (30,30), all real entries (floats), but not symmetric. The number of matrices to multiply varies between 1e3 to 1e5. Each matrix is only slightly different from previous, however they are not commutative (and at the end I need the product of all these non-commutative multiplication). Each matrix is for certain time slice, so I know how to generate each of them independently, wherever they are in the multiplication sequence. At the end, I have to produce many such matrix propagators, so any performance enhancement is welcomed.

What is the algorithm for fastest implementation of such matrix multiplication in python?

In particular -

- How to structure it? Are there fast axes and so on? preferable dimensions for rows / columns of the matrix?
- Assuming memory is not a problem, to allocate and build all matrices before multiplication, or to generate each per time step? To store each matrix in dedicated variable before multiplication, or to generate when needed and directly multiply?
- Cumulative effects of function call overheads effects when generating matrices?
- As I know how to build each, should it be parallelized? For example maybe to create batch sequences from start of the sequence and from the end, multiply them in parallel and at the end multiply the results in proper order?
- Is it preferable to use other module than numpy? Numba can be useful? or some other efficient way to compile in place to C, or use of optimized external libraries? (please give reference if so, I don't have experience in that)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For 30x30 a BLAS call is definitely the fastest way. With Numba you can only reduce the overhead. eg. this is a example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774 On very small matrices the can save a lot of time. As always it is very important to reduce the number of memory allocations as much as possible and consider CPU-cache usage. I would generate them just in time and than calculate a dot product.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the matrix multiplication would take much time. So, I would do it in a single loop. The assembling is probably the costly part here.

If you have bigger matrices, a map-reduce approach could be helpful. (split the set of matrices, apply matrix multiplication to each set and do the same for the resulting matrices)

Numpy is perfectly fine for problems like this as it is pretty optimized. (and is partly in C)

Just test how much time the matrix multiplication takes and how much the assembling. The result should indicate where you need to optimize.