# Numpy batch dot product

Tags: python, numpy, performance, linear-algebra

Suppose I have two vectors and wish to take their dot product; this is simple,

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(3)
b = np.random.rand(3)

result = np.dot(a,b)
```

If I have stacks of vectors and I want each one dotted, the most naive code is

```py
# 5 = number of vectors
a = np.random.rand(5,3)
b = np.random.rand(5,3)
result = [np.dot(aa,bb) for aa, bb in zip(a,b)]
```

Two ways to batch this computation are using a multiply and sum, and einsum,

```py
result = np.sum(a*b, axis=1)

# or
result = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b)
```

However, neither of these dispatch to the BLAS backend, and so use only a single core.  This is not super great when `N` is very large, say 1 million.

tensordot *does* dispatch to the BLAS backend.  A terrible way to do this computation with tensordot is

```py
np.diag(np.tensordot(a,b, axes=[1,1])
```

This is terrible because it allocates an `N*N` matrix, and the majority of the elements are waste work.

Another (brilliantly fast) approach is the hidden inner1d function

```py
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d

result = inner1d(a,b)
```

but it seems [this isn't going to be viable](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16983), since the issue that might export it publicly has gone stale.  And this still boils down to writing the loop in C, instead of using multiple cores.

Is there a way to get `dot`, `matmul`, or `tensordot` to do all these dot products at once, on multiple cores?

Comment: `a[:,None,:]@b[:,:,None]`.  Also try `einsum` with `optimize=True`

Comment: the matmul call doesn't use multiple cores and is much slower than inner1d (N=1024, inner1d=4usec, matmul=19usec).  Einsum with optimization has a hefty constant time tax (~25usec), but is about 10% faster for moderately large N (1 million).  I would prefer a solution that is "always good" instead of one where I need to sniff `N` and change a flag

Comment: Usually `matmul` is faster than `einsum`.  But here it must be the large batch size compared to `inner` dimension that's some how giving `einsum` the advantage.

Comment: It depends on the size of the matrices or vectors. It is also important to use some known information (eg  the vectors or matrices always have the same size), to optimize further. On larger problems parallelization is also beneficial. Example on small matrices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there is **no direct [BLAS function](http://www.netlib.org/blas/) to do that**. Using many level 1 BLAS function calls is not very efficient since using multiple threads for a very short-timed computation tends to introduce a pretty-big overhead and not using multiple threads may be sub-optimal. Still, such computation is mainly **memory-bound** and so it *scales poorly* on platform with many cores (few cores are often enough to saturate the memory bandwidth).

One simple solution is to use the **Numexpr** package which should do that quite efficiently (it should avoid the creation of temporary arrays and should also use multiple threads). However, the performance is somewhat disappointing for big arrays in this case.

The best solution appears to use **Numba** (or Cython). Numba can generate a fast code for both small and big input arrays and it is easy to parallelize the code. However, please note that managing threads introduces an overhead which can be quite big for small arrays (up to few ms on some many-core platforms).

Here is a Numexpr implementation:

```py
import numexpr as ne
expr = ne.NumExpr('sum(a * b, axis=1)')
result = expr.run(a, b)
```

Here is a (sequential) Numba implementation:

```py
import numba as nb

# Use `parallel=True` for a parallel implementation
@nb.njit('float64[:](float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])')
def multiDots(a, b):
    assert a.shape == b.shape
    n, m = a.shape
    res = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)

    # Use `nb.prange` instead of `range` to run the loop in parallel
    for i in range(n):
        s = 0.0
        for j in range(m):
            s += a[i,j] * b[i,j]
        res[i] = s

    return res

result = multiDots(a, b)
```

Here are some benchmarks on a (old) 2-core machine:

```
On small 5x3 arrays:
    np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b, optimize=True):  45.2 us
    Numba (parallel):                            12.1 us
    np.sum(a*b, axis=1):                          9.5 us
    np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b):                  6.5 us
    Numexpr:                                      3.2 us
    inner1d(a, b):                                1.8 us
    Numba (sequential):                           1.3 us

On small 1000000x3 arrays:
    np.sum(a*b, axis=1):                         27.8 ms
    Numexpr:                                     15.3 ms
    np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b, optimize=True):   9.0 ms
    np.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b):                  8.8 ms
    Numba (sequential):                           6.8 ms
    inner1d(a, b):                                6.5 ms
    Numba (parallel):                             5.3 ms
```

The sequential Numba implementation gives a good trade-off. You can use a switch if you really want the best performance. Choosing the best `n` threshold in a platform-independent way is not so easy though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, I am totally and completely uninterested in numba.  I was burned by it severely in the past, and even if those problems have been fixed, I am disinterested in it as a dependency for either CPU or GPU code.  The sequential numba function is slower than `inner1d` from numpy, so it isn't even generating very good code with LLVM.