# Can i rewrite this code to make it work faster?

Tags: python, performance, loops

Is it actually possible to make this run faster? I need to get half of all possible grids (all elements can be either -1 or 1) of size 4*Lx (for counting energies in Ising model).

```
def get_grid(Lx):
    a = list()
    count = 0
    t = list(product([1,-1], repeat=Lx))
    for i in range(len(t)):
        for j in range(len(t)):
            for k in range(len(t)):
                for l in range(len(t)):
                    count += 1
                    a.append([t[i], t[j], t[k], t[l]])
                    if count == 2**(Lx*4)/2:
                        return np.array(a)
```

Tried using numba, but that didn't work out.

Comment: Some problems of this nature may be better suited using sets or sparse arrays, rather than having to initialize everything, especially if each element is only one of two possible values.

Comment: Can you explain what the code is intended to calculate, for people who don't have a physics background? I see several possible inefficiencies, but it's possible you intend them. Can you also provide a definition for `product` and an example value for `Lx`?

Comment: Code is intended to calculate half of all possible grids, which will be used later to count energies. Grids - Matrices of size 4*Lx, each element of matrix can be either 1 or -1(spin), so i need to get 2^(Lx*4) matrices for all possible variants. Every matrix represents system state, and to find mean energy of that system i need to count energy for all possible system states, i.e. count it for half of all possible sets of grid values(function for energy is even, that's why i need only half of states). Lx is integer that could be from 2 to 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Numba does not like lists. If you want an efficient code, then you need to **operate on arrays** (except when you really do not know the size at runtime and estimating it is hard/slow). Here the size of the output array is already known so it is better to preallocate it and then fill it. Numba does not like much high-level features like generators, you should **prefer using basic loops** which are faster (as long as they are executed in a JITed function). The Cartesian product can be replaced by the efficient computation of an array based on the bits of an increasing integer. The whole computation is mainly **memory-bound** so it is better to **use small integer datatypes** like `uint8` which take 4 times less space in RAM (and thus about 4 times faster to fill). Here is the resulting code:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int8[:,:,:](int64,)')
def get_grid_numba(Lx):
    t = np.empty((2**Lx, Lx), dtype=np.int8)
    for i in range(2**Lx):
        for j in range(Lx):
            t[i, Lx-1-j] = 1 - 2 * ((i >> j) & 1)
    outSize = 2**(Lx*4 - 1)
    out = np.empty((outSize, 4, Lx), dtype=np.int8)
    cur = 0
    for i in range(len(t)):
        for j in range(len(t)):
            for k in range(len(t)):
                for l in range(len(t)):
                    out[cur, 0, :] = t[i, :]
                    out[cur, 1, :] = t[j, :]
                    out[cur, 2, :] = t[k, :]
                    out[cur, 3, :] = t[l, :]
                    cur += 1
                    if cur == outSize:
                        return out
    return out
```

For `Lx=4`, the initial code takes 66.8 ms while this Numba code takes 0.36 ms on my i5-9600KF processor. It is thus **185 times faster**.

---

Note that the size of the output array exponentially grows very quickly. For `Lx=7`, the output shape is `(134217728, 4, 7)` and it takes 3.5 GiB of RAM. The Numba code takes 2.47 s to generate it, that is 1.4 GiB/s. If this is not enough to you, then you can write specific implementation from Lx=1 to Lx=8, use loops for the `out` slice assignment and even use multiple threads for Lx>=5. For small arrays, you can pre-compute them once. This should be an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: It is not necessary to really "write" specific implementations. Maybe it makes sense to also mention using a generator function, for common Lx, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774

Comment: That's very cool and fast implementation, thank you. Maybe you can explain how this implementaion of cartesian product using bitwise operations works or maybe give some sources with explanation of it? I mean t[i, Lx-1-j] = 1 - 2 * ((i >> j) & 1) part in your code.

Comment: @max9111 Yeah. I was thinking about writting only a master function calling this function mark as `inline` with a `Lx` constant so the compiler can generate a code specialized for each `Lx` from 1 to 8 (actually 2 to 6 is enough for the OP). But generated JIT functions also works and can actually be better if only few Lx are used in the code (and the overhead of JIT compilation at runtime is not a problem). Thank you for the reference/example.

Comment: @DisplayName1234 The idea of `(i >> j) & 1` is to extract the `j`th bit from `i`. The `1 - 2 * ...` is used to convert the 0/1 bit value to 1/-1 values. The iteration over all `i` values from 0 to `2**Lx` is used to generate all combination.

Comment: Caching should also work now for generators. I have testet it for Lx 1 to 8. First gen needs about 4s, second generation after restarting the kernel gives 0.4s. This functions can also be thrown in a small python wrapper, which chooses the specialized versions or a general version. Maybe using a simple dict...