# How to speed up loops of numpy array calculations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to do the following loop with some calculations using numpy arrays. The size of the array can be as big as roughly `(5000,1000,3)`. I am not sure I can vectorize it further as some variables are dynamically generated.

Further I need to do this loop more than 100 times with different parameter inputs, so this gets much worse.

Any advice to improve it is much appreciated.

```
import itertools
from numpy import random
import time


def get_p(payoffs):
    allmax = payoffs.max(axis=1)[:, None]
    findmax = payoffs - allmax
    mask = ((findmax[:, 1, :] == 0) & (findmax[:, 2, :] == 0))
    findmax[:, 1, :][mask] = -1

    mask = ((findmax[:, 0, :] == 0) & (findmax[:, 1, :] == 0))
    findmax[:, 0, :][mask] = -1

    mask = ((findmax[:, 0, :] == 0) & (findmax[:, 1, :] == 0) & (findmax[:, 2, :] == 0))
    findmax[:, 0, :][mask] = -1
    findmax[:, 1, :][mask] = -1

    p = np.where(findmax < 0, 0.0, 1.0).transpose(0, 2, 1)
    return p


payoffs = np.array([[9, 8, 15],
                    [10, 4, 15],
                    [2, 30, 12]])

rng = np.random.default_rng()
possible_path = np.array(list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(0, 3), 100)))
current_prob = rng.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1000)
current_prob = current_prob.T
p = rng.uniform(0., 1.0, size=1000)
b = rng.uniform(0., 1.0, size=1000)
c = rng.uniform(0., 1.0, size=1000)
d = rng.uniform(0., 1.0, size=1000)
all_payoffs=[]
past_weight = np.zeros((1000,))
past_belief = np.zeros((3,1000))

for t in range(0,possible_path.shape[1]):
    action = possible_path[:, t]
    num_path = np.arange(action.shape[0])
    p_l1 = np.zeros((action.shape[0],3))
    p_l1[num_path,action] = 1.0

    if t == 0:
        current_signal = current_prob.T * (1 - p)[:, None] + p_l1[:,None] * p[:,None]
    else:
        current_signal = p_l1[:, None] * p[:, None] + current_prob.transpose(1, 0, 2) * (1 - p)[:, None]
    current_weight = past_weight * c
    if t == 0:
        current_belief = (current_signal.transpose(1, 2, 0) + (past_belief * current_weight)[:, None].transpose(2,0,1)) / (1 + current_weight)[:,None][:,None]
    else:
        current_belief = (current_signal.transpose(1, 2, 0) + (past_belief * current_weight[:, None][:, None])) / (1 + current_weight)[:,None][:,None]

    current_payoffs = payoffs @ current_belief
    current_prob = get_p(current_payoffs)

    past_belief = current_belief
    past_weight = current_weight + 1
```

Comment: Usually the key to speeding up loops is to replace them with whole-array compiled method calls.  That moves the iteration from python-level to compiled code.  But to do that you/we need to understand the loop (inner most for a start).  For me that's almost a visual task - picturing, and if need be, reimagining the action.  Failing that there's the option of using `cython` or `numba` to compile the code directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it simply, **you reach the limits of Numpy**.

First of all, you create pretty big array (>100 MiB) which are typically stored in the **slow DRAM**. Some of them are **temporary arrays** which are filled in memory (DRAM) and then read back which is inefficient since they could have been created **chunk by chunk** in the CPU cache. Numpy does not (currently) provide a way to speed this up because it would require to analyse the whole code (or at least expressions) so to generate a fast compiled code (which typically requires a just-in-time compiler or at least a pre-compilation step so not to be slow at runtime). On top of that, newly created temporary arrays are slow to fill in memory because *first-touch* typically results in **very-slow page faults**. The key to avoid this is to avoid allocating/filling temporary arrays and try to reuse arrays as much as possible. While this is often possible by pre-allocating arrays and using the `out` parameters of Numpy functions, it is also cumbersome to do and make the code much harder to maintain (for non-trivial codes like this). Last but not least, the computation is done serially because Numpy does not use multiple threads (it would not be very efficient anyway for memory-bound codes and many Numpy codes tends to be memory-bound because of the above issues).

That said, you can mitigate some of the Numpy limitations with **Numexpr**. This module can optimize (basic) expressions and perform the computations using multiple threads. This means it can avoid creating some temporary arrays. Multi-threading can mitigate a part of the page-fault overhead (especially on Linux, but not much on Windows).

Here is the resulting (unchecked) code:

```py
import itertools
from numpy import random
import time
import numexpr as ne

def get_p(payoffs):
    allmax = payoffs.max(axis=1)[:, None]
    findmax = payoffs - allmax
    p0 = findmax[:, 0, :]
    p1 = findmax[:, 1, :]
    p2 = findmax[:, 2, :]
    mask = ne.evaluate('(p1 == 0) & (p2 == 0)')
    p1[mask] = -1

    mask = ne.evaluate('(p0 == 0) & (p1 == 0)')
    p0[mask] = -1

    mask = ne.evaluate('(p0 == 0) & (p1 == 0) & (p2 == 0)')
    p0[mask] = -1
    p1[mask] = -1

    p = np.where(findmax < 0, 0.0, 1.0).transpose(0, 2, 1)
    return p


payoffs = np.array([[9, 8, 15],
                    [10, 4, 15],
                    [2, 30, 12]])

rng = np.random.default_rng()
possible_path = np.array(list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(0, 3), 100)))
current_prob = rng.dirichlet(np.ones(3),size=1000)
current_prob = current_prob.T
p = rng.uniform(0., 1.0, size=1000)
b = rng.uniform(0., 1.0, size=1000)
c = rng.uniform(0., 1.0, size=1000)
d = rng.uniform(0., 1.0, size=1000)
all_payoffs=[]
past_weight = np.zeros((1000,))
past_belief = np.zeros((3,1000))

for t in range(0,possible_path.shape[1]):
    action = possible_path[:, t]
    num_path = np.arange(action.shape[0])
    p_l1 = np.zeros((action.shape[0],3))
    p_l1[num_path,action] = 1.0

    if t == 0:
        p1, p2, p3, p4 = current_prob.T, (1 - p)[:, None], p_l1[:,None], p[:,None]
    else:
        p1, p2, p3, p4 = p_l1[:, None], p[:, None], current_prob.transpose(1, 0, 2), (1 - p)[:, None]
    current_signal = ne.evaluate('p1 * p2 + p3 * p4')
    current_weight = past_weight * c
    p1 = current_signal.transpose(1, 2, 0)
    p3 = (1 + current_weight)[:,None][:,None]
    if t == 0:
        p2 = (past_belief * current_weight)[:, None].transpose(2,0,1)
    else:
        p2 = past_belief * current_weight[:, None][:, None]
    current_belief = ne.evaluate('(p1 + p2) / p3')

    current_payoffs = payoffs @ current_belief
    current_prob = get_p(current_payoffs)

    past_belief = current_belief
    past_weight = current_weight + 1
```

This is **2.7 times faster** on my 6-core i5-9600KF CPU (on Windows). This is not much faster because the code is still rather memory-bound and also because Numexpr can generate a code less optimized than Numpy though using more threads make the computation overall often still faster.

Besides, `payoffs @ current_belief` is not optimized with Numexpr. While matrix multiplications should run in parallel on most platforms (thanks to optimized parallel BLAS library implementations called by Numpy), it is certainly not the case here since the left-hand-side matrix is very small which tends to cause the internal BLAS calls to be inefficient in this specific case due to the way Numpy works (more specifically due to broadcasting here) and BLAS are designed (multi-threading is generally disabled in this case or simply useless). There is a way to make this operation efficient with multiple thread but one need to do that manually.

If you want **to optimize this further, then Numba is the way to go**, especially for computing `payoffs @ current_belief` more efficiently (and more generally the whole code), and avoiding the code to be memory-bound. For more information, please read [Explicit matrix multiplication much faster than numpy.matmul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76729145/explicit-matrix-multiplication-much-faster-than-numpy-matmul/76732704#76732704)