# How to speed up Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to do the following using `numpy`. Because the size of `aa` is large, using `numpy` is slow. I am trying to speed it up by using `numba`, there is some improvement, but I would like speed it further, because it is a part of another loop. Any advice is much appreciated!

Using `numpy`:

```
def get_prob(aa):
    allmax = aa.max(axis=1)[:, None]
    findmax = aa - allmax
    mask = ((findmax[:,1,:]==0)&(findmax[:,2,:]==0))
    findmax[:, 1, :][mask] = -1

    mask = ((findmax[:, 0, :] == 0) & (findmax[:, 1, :] == 0))
    findmax[:, 0, :][mask] = -1

    mask = ((findmax[:, 0, :] == 0) & (findmax[:, 1, :] == 0) & (findmax[:, 2, :] == 0))
    findmax[:, 0, :][mask] = -1
    findmax[:, 1, :][mask] = -1

    p = np.where(findmax < 0, 0.0, 1.0).transpose(0,2,1)
    return p
```

Using `numba`:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def get_prob_nb(aa,num_params,num_action):
    p=np.zeros_like(aa)

    for i in range(num_params):
        for j in range(num_action):
            a1 = aa[i, 0, j]
            a2 = aa[i, 1, j]
            a3 = aa[i, 2, j]
            if a1>a2 and a1>a3:
                p[i, 0, j] = 1.
            elif a2>=a1 and a2>a3:
                p[i, 1, j] = 1.
            elif a3>=a2 and a3>=a1:
                p[i, 2, j] = 1.

    p = p.transpose(0, 2, 1)
    return p

aa=rng.uniform(0.0, 1.0, 9000000)
aa=aa.reshape(1000,3,3000)
start = time.time()
get_prob_nb(aa, 1000, 3000)
print("elapse", time.time()-start)
```

Comment: From a brief look, the Numba loop looks reasonably optimal (e.g., things like access of right-most index in the inner loop). I guess one obvious way is to run the loop in parallel, but that's probably not what the question is about.

Comment: As stated in [the answer of your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77991562/12939557) the code is bound by *page faults*. This is still true for the Numba code of this post (at least, clearly on my machine). Thus, *pre-allocating* and *filling* the array `p` only once will speed up multiple calls of this function. If you do only one call to this function, then the *only* way to speed thing up is to use *multiple threads* so to do the page fault in parallel and also increase the performance of the computational part.

Comment: Note that page faults are expensive because of zero page filling which is needed for *security reasons*. It is possible to disable it on some OS (e.g. Linux) but at the expensive of a possibly huge security concerns when unsafe codes can be executed on the target machine (e.g. leak of passwords).

Comment: Are you sure that you want to speed up this function? The runtime of the get_p function in your previous post was about 20% of the total, and is not even a bottleneck. If we are working on the same subject, then speeding up get_p is ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_prob_keepdims(aa):
    max_values = aa.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    p = np.equal(aa, max_values).astype(float)
    return p.transpose(0, 2, 1)
```

The function `get_prob_keepdims` utilizes the `keepdims=True` parameter in its computation, which maintains the original array's dimension after performing the `max` operation across a specific axis. Based on my understanding of the provided code, I believe this function should operate the same as the original `get_prob` function.

In my 100 iterations test, using keepdims yielded slightly faster results than using Numba without parallel on a Mac M1.

Answer (score -1):

There's a surprisingly [simple way to parallelize](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.11/prange.html) your numba call:

```py
@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def get_prob_nb_parallel(aa, num_params, num_action):
    p = np.zeros_like(aa)

    for i in numba.prange(num_params):
        for j in range(num_action):
            a1 = aa[i, 0, j]
            a2 = aa[i, 1, j]
            a3 = aa[i, 2, j]
            if a1 > a2 and a1 > a3:
                p[i, 0, j] = 1.
            elif a2 >= a1 and a2 > a3:
                p[i, 1, j] = 1.
            elif a3 >= a2 and a3 >= a1:
                p[i, 2, j] = 1.

    p = p.transpose(0, 2, 1)
    return p
```

Running your test, I saw an time improvement of ~30% versus `get_prob_nb`.

Comment: Using more core for a 1.3x speed up is quite a waste of resources (the hammer method). I get a speed-up of 1.55x by just preallocating the output as described in the above comment and still using 1 core (and significantly less energy).

Comment: With 6x more cores, I get a slight performance speed-up over just pre-allocating the array (<1.1x). But preallocating the array AND using more core make this much faster (5x~6x). This is because of page-faults, as explained in the above comment. There are other ways to speed this up without using more resources (which should be the last solution).